# Einstein Analytics / Analytics Studio (Tableau) - Accessing Event Logs for Flow Executions

Tags: einstein-analytics, developer, analytics, eventlogfile, tableau-crm

We are looking into using the Analytics Studio (Tableau) to create dashboards related to System Performance. One item we'd like to drill down further is the runtime on automations (WFRs, PBs, Flows, etc).

In Analytics Studio, I can confirm we can create a Dataset on the object [Event Log Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm). I can also isolate the returned logs by Event Type 'Flow Execution'.

Per these docs on [Flow Execution Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_flowexecution.htm), we should be able to access fields available to this event type: TOTAL_EXECUTION_TIME, NUMBER_OF_INTERVIEWS, NUMBER_OF_ERRORS, etc. I have reviewed the [Developer docs for EventLogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) and it states 'To view the underlying event data, query the LogFile field'. However, this field is not available as a selection when setting up the Dataset for the Event Log Files object.

I'm having difficulty determining how to create a Dataset within Analytics Studio that will return the fields listed above for FlowExecution event types. I've found helpful documentation on setting up an app as well as Datasets, but nothing specific to automations monitoring. Has anyone here had experience setting up dashboards on Flow Executions or can point me in the direction of documentation more specific to this use-case?

Additional Resources Utilized so far:

- [SFBen - Einstein Analytics Dataflow Transformations Overview](https://www.salesforceben.com/einstein-analytics-dataflow-transformations-overview/)
- [Trailheads on Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es-MX/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro)
- [Trailhead - Query Event Log Files](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es-MX/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_query) (this does not seem specific to the Analytics App)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave this, as I was looking for something similar and could not find anything.  Finally found a SF Limitation article on EvenLogFiles and the CRM Analytics App.

[Limitations on Event Monitoring Objects EventLogFile and LoginEvent in CRM Analytics](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383944&type=1)

It looks like you need to either extract them all, via the API, or use their pre-built app.  Most likely things like PBs,WFs, and Flows won't be in the data that they display.